# Adding new item list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list where the data is coming from a csv file. I want to add functionality that when the user add a new column in the csv file a new item list is added in the html. The csv file is locally hosted and when updated it's just overwritten with the new file. Is this possible with jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: If the file is on the client you could use the HTML5 [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/), but it won't be very cross-browser compatible.

Comment: I don't need to upload the file through the page. The csv file is just hosted locally in the same folder as the code. Then with ajax getting the data from the file.

Comment: I took "locally" to mean on the clients machine. You're saying the CSV file is hosted on the server? What are you using to serve the HTML? PHP? Node? Rails? jQuery is a client-side technology, not server-side.

Comment: Yes the csv file is hosted on the client machine and when is updated with a new column a new list item is added that is what I want to achieve instead of adding the list item manually.

Comment: As I said before, the only way for a browser to ask questions of the local file system (that I know of) is through the HTML5 File API. You can inspect the file's contents using the method [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Comment: The process that I was thinking is user update csv file locally with new data and if a new column is added to the csv file a new list item is added to the html then uploaded to the folder where the code is after the user refreshes the page and see the new data.

Comment: I understand that, but you are restricted by the technologies that you are using. Browsers are typically protective of the local file system. You may consider using something like [Electron.js](http://electron.atom.io/) to package up a desktop Node application (which can easily query the file system). But it sounds like this may be too advanced.